# issue smooth scrolling to page anchor from link inside google map info window

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, smooth-scrolling

I have a link to a page anchor inside a google maps info window. The problem is it won't smooth scroll to this anchor, it just jumps. Smooth scrolling works on all other links on my page. I think this is happening because these particular links are not coming from the html, but are being put there by the google maps code, and therefor are not being noticed by the script.

Here the part of my google maps code that generates the links-

```
[   '<div id="infoboxcontent">' +
        '<a href ="#project1"><h4>Project 1</h4>' +
        '<p>Description</p></a>' +
        '</div>'    
    , -33.890542, 151.274856],
```

and here is the smooth scrolling script i'm using from from css-tricks

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname     == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Can anyone here help me? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the infowindow links are not created yet when you call the smooth scrolling script (document ready).

Wrap the smooth-scrolling code in a function. For example:

```
function smoothScroll() {

    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Call that function from your document ready statement:

```
$(function() {

    smoothScroll();
});
```

Add a listener on the `domready` event of the infowindow and call the function again from there:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {

    smoothScroll();
});
```

You might want to adjust the smoothScroll function so that it takes a scope as argument (to avoid reprocessing all the other links again...).

Comment: Excellent! This works. But When I click any link, it smooth scrolls to the anchor then freezes/locks the scrolling. Is this what you were referring to with adjusting the smoothScroll function? I'm not sure how to do that but I will try and figure it out

Comment: No. And I don't know why it does. Do you have a live example? By adjusting the function I meant to let it know where it should apply the smooth-scroll effect since you already apply it on document-ready. Just for performance matters, but that's some tweaking.

Comment: It was something else in my code causing this issue. Works perfectly now. Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding listeners, try adapting your script to use the [jQuery on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery(document.body).on('click','a[href*=#]:not([href=#])',function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = jQuery(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            jQuery(target).addClass("target");
            jQuery('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000,'swing',function(){jQuery(target).removeClass("target");});
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    }); 
});
```